# Magmi blank page while importing products

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi, optimization

I am using Magmi on a regular basis to mass import products.

Unfortunately, every 100-like products the application freezes as shown on the following image:
[image]

The "solution" I found so far is to cancel the importation and re-running it using the option "create new items only, skip existing ones" so that it skips the ones that have been added in the past.

Can someone explain me what is happening? Is there any way to make it run with no interruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running out of memory. Many times, when there is no memory, it dies a silent death. Check your php.ini `memory_limit` and also the memory limit in your .htaccess file. Increase as needed.

I had a client with the exact same issue, it was all memory based. Magmi is inefficient and buggy in my experience.

Comment: @clementgamache did my answer help you?

Comment: when I asked the question I was on a shared hosting, so I could not change the memory limit. I recently switched for a dedicated hosting and changed it. It was a success! Thanks a lot :)